# Django: No Such Table

Tags: python, django

I'm running into an error while trying to extend my user model.  I have a model created that takes in some more fields that I would like to be attached to the user as seen here:

accounts/models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    US_STATES_OR_CAN_PROVINCES = (
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
        ('AS', 'American Samoa'),
        ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
        ('CA', 'California'),
        ('CO', 'Colorado'),
        ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
        ('DC', 'District of Columbia'),
        ('DE', 'Delaware'),
        ('FL', 'Florida'),
        ('GA', 'Georgia'),
        ('GU', 'Guam'),
        ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
        ('IA', 'Iowa'),
        ('ID', 'Idaho'),
        ('IL', 'Illinois'),
        ('IN', 'Indiana'),
        ('KS', 'Kansas'),
        ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
        ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
        ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
        ('MD', 'Maryland'),
        ('ME', 'Maine'),
        ('MI', 'Michigan'),
        ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
        ('MO', 'Missouri'),
        ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
        ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
        ('MT', 'Montana'),
        ('NA', 'National'),
        ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
        ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
        ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
        ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
        ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
        ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
        ('NV', 'Nevada'),
        ('NY', 'New York'),
        ('OH', 'Ohio'),
        ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
        ('OR', 'Oregon'),
        ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
        ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
        ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
        ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
        ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
        ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
        ('TX', 'Texas'),
        ('UT', 'Utah'),
        ('VA', 'Virginia'),
        ('VI', 'Virgin Islands'),
        ('VT', 'Vermont'),
        ('WA', 'Washington'),
        ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
        ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
        ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
        ('AB', 'Alberta'),
        ('BC','British Columbia'),
        ('MB', 'Manitoba'),
        ('NB', 'New Brunswick'),
        ('NL', 'Newfoundland and Labrador'),
        ('NT', 'Northwest Territories'),
        ('NS', 'Nova Scotia'),
        ('NU', 'Nunavut'),
        ('ON', 'Ontario'),
        ('PE', 'Prince Edward Island'),
        ('QC', 'Quebec'),
        ('SK', 'Saskatchewan'),
        ('YT', 'Yukon')
    )
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('USA', 'United States'),
        ('CAN', 'Canada')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    company_website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    company_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    company_state = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                            choices=US_STATES_OR_CAN_PROVINCES)
    company_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    company_country =models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES,
                                            blank=False)
```

I am then trying to access these new details inside the admin page like this:

accounts/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import Customer
# Register your models here.

# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class CustomerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Customer
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'customers'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (CustomerInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

When I run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, everything migrates fine, but my `Customer` model is nowhere to be found in the database. I verified by running `inspectdb`.

This is my error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/
no such table: accounts_customer
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: accounts_customer
```

This seems like django 101 but I have to be missing something.

Comment: P.S. if anyone has a better way to serve the choices for state or province based on country, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've forgotten to add `'accounts'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

This means that the required migrations will not have been created when you invoked `makemigrations`, and thus not run when you invoked `migrate`.

Comment: additionally, make sure the accounts app has a migrations module

Comment: Meshy, thanks for the comment. I forgot to post my settings.py file but yes I do have accounts inside of installed apps.

I think what fixed it was that I completely deleted the migrations folder from my accounts app. then basically re created it. re ran makemigrations and migrate and now it works perfect. 

Something to note that I tried multiple times deleting all of the migrations inside of the folder and that didn't work. Ultimately making sure that the app had a migrations module helped me fix this.

Comment: I also ended up deleting my database and starting over, that may have been the actual fix versus deleting the migrations folder.  Not possible for everyone that has this issue but my project is so early that there really isn't any data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run migrations specifically for that app, like so:

```
python manage.py makemigrations accounts
python manage.py migrate accounts
```

I had a specific case a few days ago where there was no migrations folder inside the app, and it only worked after explicitly stating the app name.

In any case, you will be able to extract more information regarding your problem should there be an issue running the commands above.

Comment: TGO, I did run these specific commands multiple times and it kept coming back good, it would basically just skip my Customer model every time. See my comment above, completely deleting the migrations folder inside of my accounts app and recreating it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You have to **delete your database** and do the **migrations** and **migrate** again.
It works for me